# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is not called for Integer preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have come across this problem, and it took quite a bit of time to figure out the matter, so I'm sharing my experience.

I'm using SharedPreferences listener to pass data between a BroadcastReceiver (sitting on AlarmManager events, but it doesn't matter for the subject) and my Activity. Previously I used intents for the same purpose, but an idea (crazy? May be using Handlers is a better pattern for this?) came to my mind, to do it via a SharedPreferences listener.

So I'm registering in the Activity **OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener**, and in BroadcastReceiver I just use an editor on SharedPreferences, put a value there, and receive it in the Activity. Looks plain so far. And it works, **BUT** not for **integer** preferences. So, for example if I call

```
pref.edit().putString("0").commit();
```

the **OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener** is called, but if I use this:

```
pref.edit().putInt(0).commit();
```

it is **not** called!

I guess the matter is that SharedPreferences were designed for Settings, and there's no SharedPreference of type integer in Android, we can't specify integer value for EditTextPreference. So, for this reason, or some other, OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is not called for Preferences of type int. Beware!

Huh, now I think I should use a Handler with messages instead....

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Otto (https://github.com/square/otto), EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), MicroBus (https://github.com/konmik/MicroBus)

Comment: Voting this answer up for good info. Though I would use Handler as usual ))

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SharedPreferences listeners to exchange data between activities, except for SettingsActivity. Pass notifications via Handler messages instead.

Comment: I forgot to say that in this particular case I ended with a String preference instead of integer one, it was the shortest fix